# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'None'

Tags: python-3.x

I cloned a new project and want to start working on it. The requiremnets.txt installed successfully but then started having issues with the above error.
I tried `pip install none` and the installation was successful, After trying to do `python manage.py runserver` the same error still occurs.
i have been to `https://pypi.org/project/none/`, but there's not so much is provided.
i have also searched for solutions on the web but limited helpful information was found. You can help me figure out what i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I checked it locally. It's working.

Do this

```
import none
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the  `.env` file in my root folder where the manage.py I created the `.env` file in the specified location and configure the database settings and hurray